# There is a table in a/the kitchen? (if 1st sentence)

Tags: articles, usage

I'm confused as to why internet shows a lot of hits like 'There is a table in '**the**' kitchen?' after 'There is a table in'. Is it because the sentence(s) are assumed to be already in the middle of the story?

If 1st sentence, when which particular kitchen this is, is not defined yet, I understand correct one is 'There is a table in '**a**' kitchen'?

Comment: Please provide references to where you saw this. Google shows a lot of hits in different contexts: many are descriptions of property for sale/rent where it's obvious the kitchen is the one in the property. And there are some cases in language learning websites, where there's no requirement to be identifying a particular kitchen because it's just a random sentence. I can't see any examples that match your description where it's the first sentence and there is no prior context but it's still part of a larger text.

Comment: The sentence *There is a table in **a** kitchen* has very little claim to the description “correct.” It makes a claim of existence that, pragmatically, would not come as news to anyone: Some kitchen somewhere contains a table.

Answer (score 1):

"Let me tell you a story. Once upon a time, there was a table in a kitchen. The kitchen was very large with tiled walls." [a generality, and notice how one moves from a to the]

"Let me tell you a story. Once, the table in the kitchen of my country house started to wobble, so I decided to try and fix that."

**the** kitchen is specific.

If I am having a conversation with someone and talk about "the kitchen", I'm most likely referring to the kitchen in my own house or some house we have been discussing. "the kitchen" is always specific, "a kitchen" is not.

Comment: ""the kitchen", I'm most likely referring to the kitchen in my own house" - is it the short answer? If 1st sentence is "there is a table in the kitchen.", that means a person gives information that "there is a table in their kitchen."?

Comment: @Martian2020 The kitchen could belong to someone else, yes. It is the kitchen in the context they know about from the situation.

Comment: So "there is a table in the kitchen." cannot be at the start of a story? ... Unless the story is part of something bigger so that it has been hinted already which specific kitchen it is?

Comment: @Martian2020 I have done my best here. The point is that "a" is general and "the" is specific.